# Divide and Conquer algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

There is this one problem in some online judge that I have no clue on how to get accepted.

The problem goes like this first line contained two number

```
N (0 < N < 2^18) 
M (0 < M < 2^20)
```

The second line contained `N` numbers

```
ai (0 < ai < 2^40)
```

The question is how many `X` are there that satisfied:

```
M = floor(X/a1) + floor(X/a2) + ... + floor(X/an)
```

My naive solution:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long n,m,i,j,haha,sum;
int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    haha = 0;
    long long ar[n+5];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> ar[i];
    sort(ar,ar+n);
    for(i = ar[0]+1; i < m*ar[0]; i++){
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) sum += i/ar[j];
        if (sum == m) haha += 1;
        else if (sum >= m) break;
    }
    cout << haha << endl;
}
```

**Update1:**
My binary search solution (still didn't pass the time limit):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long n,m,i,l,r,mid,ans,tmp,cnt,haha;
long long ar[2621440];
long long func(long long x){
    haha = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) haha += x/ar[i];
    return haha;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> ar[i];
    sort(ar,ar+n);
    l = ar[0];
    r = ar[0]*m;
    mid = (l+r)/2;
    tmp = func(mid);
    while (tmp != m){
        mid = (l+r)/2;
        tmp = func(mid);
        if (l == r) break;
        if (tmp < m) l = mid+1;
        else if (tmp > m) r = mid-1;
        else break;
    }
    ans = 0;
    if (tmp == m) ans += 1;
    cnt = mid;
    while (func(cnt-1) == m){
        ans += 1;
        cnt -= 1;
    }
    cnt = mid;
    while (func(cnt+1) == m){
        ans += 1;
        cnt += 1;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the question link?

Comment: @User_Targaryen The question is written in my native language and from a local online judge. Proving the link wont help. If you really want to know though [link](https://training.ia-toki.org/training/curriculums/1/courses/11/chapters/53/problems/247/).

Comment: is it actually possible to have several values of X satisfying this equation? i think only one is possible (if actually possible), no?

Comment: @mangusta for example we got n = 3 and m = 10. And we got a1 = 4, a2 = 6, and a3 = 8. We got four possibilities of X (20,21,22,and,23).

Comment: yes, right. but why do you start checking values of X from the smallest+1 ? you should start from just smallest. for example if M=1, and N=3 and values are 1,6,7. according to your logic, you start from X=2, but if X=1 the equation is solved

Comment: @mangusta well, you are right. I should start from the smallest. But the real problem here is the time limit and complexity. I can't pass the 1 second time limit.

Comment: @Aldihilmanr if the problem is supposed to be solved by D&C, i think the only option here is to use binary search. the predicate is "Does X make this expression equal to M?", if no, then you go to left or right, along sorted X values, if yes, you stop and inspect the neighborhood of X

Comment: the domain of X should be carefully selected, and as we see, it starts from smallest a_i.  stop point is M*smallest inclusively

Comment: The problem looks pretty linear to me. Take the lowest number `ai` and return it. Did I overlook anything?

Comment: @mangusta I did what you suggest, got a higher score. But still wont pass the time limit.

Comment: @Aldihilmanr are you sorting or just searching for the lowest `ai`? Other possibility is to use C style input (tends to be faster in competitions).

Comment: @grek40 Wont work. For example `N` = 3 and `M` = 10. And we got `a1` = 1, `a2` = 1, and `a3` = 1. We got no possibilities of `X`.

Comment: @kyticka did that too on my other code. It doesn't pass the time limit too, and it doesn't have a higher score from the last one.

Comment: @Aldihilmanr ok, gotta rethink it.

Comment: Have you actually tried binary search? You are not going to pass the time limit without it.

Comment: @n.m. Yes I have tried using binary search. Didn't pass the time limit.

Comment: Show your attempt at binary search then. It makes no sense to discuss linear search.

Comment: You fall back to linear search which can easily eat up all of your time. Instead, you should do two slightly different binary searches, one that finds the lower bound and one that finds the upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got accepted (finally) using two binary search (each for lower bound, and upper bound) with this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long n,m,i,l,r,mid1,mid2,ans,tmp,cnt,haha,k;
long long ar[26214400];
long long func(long long x){
    haha = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) haha += x/ar[k];
    return haha;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> ar[i];
    sort(ar,ar+n);
    l = ar[0];
    r = ar[0]*m;
    mid1 = (l+r)/2;
    tmp = func(mid1);
    while (l < r){
        mid1 = (l+r)/2;
        tmp = func(mid1);
        if (tmp < m) l = mid1+1;
        else if (tmp > m) r = mid1-1;
        else r = mid1-1;
    }
    mid1 = l; //lower bound
    l = ar[0];
    r = ar[0]*m;
    mid2 = (l+r)/2;
    tmp = func(mid2);
    while (l < r){
        mid2 = (l+r)/2;
        tmp = func(mid2);
        if (tmp < m) l = mid2+1;
        else if (tmp > m) r = mid2-1;
        else l = mid2+1;
    }
    mid2 = r; //upper bound
    while (mid1 <= mid2 and func(mid1) != m) mid1 += 1;
    while (mid2 >= mid1 and func(mid2) != m) mid2 -= 1;
    ans = mid2-mid1+1;
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Going with the binary search approach, here is my new code:

```
// compute X/ai sum
long long summarize(long long ar[], long long n, long long X)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += X/ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

bool get_range(long long ar[], int n, int m, pair<long long, long long>& range)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    long long x;
    // reduce range
    while (range.first < range.second)
    {
        x = (range.first + range.second) / 2;

        sum = summarize(ar, n, x);
        if (sum < m)
        {
            range.first = x + 1;
        }
        else if (sum > m)
        {
            range.second = x;
        }
        else if (x == range.first)
        {
            return true; // single element
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (sum != m)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // check surroundings for lower / upper bound.
    sum = summarize(ar, n, range.first);
    if (sum != m)
    {
        auto r1 = make_pair(range.first + 1, x);
        if (get_range(ar, n, m, r1))
        {
            range.first = r1.first;
        }
        else
        {
            range.first = x;
        }
    }
    sum = summarize(ar, n, range.second - 1);
    if (sum != m)
    {
        auto r2 = make_pair(x + 1, range.second - 1);
        if (get_range(ar, n, m, r2))
        {
            range.second = r2.second;
        }
        else
        {
            range.second = x + 1;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    long long *ar = new long long[n];
    long long ar_min = LLONG_MAX;
    for(long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> ar[i];
        ar_min = min(ar[i], ar_min);
    }
    // initial range of possible X values
    auto range = make_pair(m / (ar_min * n), m * ar_min);
    if (get_range(ar, n, m, range))
    {
        cout << (range.second - range.first) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }
}
```

Core functionality is the `get_range` function, which takes a possible range (`[range.first, range.second)`, so second is **not** part of the range) and reduces the range so all elements in range satisfy the condition. It is first iteratively adjusting range bounds until the middle of the range is part of the result or until it's clear that there is no result in range. Then, if there is any result, it is recursively checking the sub-ranges below and above the found result in order to retrieve the bounds of the whole result range.

**Version 1**

You are only dealing with positive numbers greater than zero.

```
M = floor(X/a1) + floor(X/a2) + ... + floor(X/an)
```

For every sub-term `floor(X/a1)`, there is `floor(X1/ai) <= floor(X2/ai)` if `X1 < X2`. So the only possible `X` values resulting in `M` are those, where `floor(X1/ai) == floor(X2/ai)` for all `i` (or all `ai`).

For each `ai` this is exactly the Range of `X1=k*ai` until `X2=k*ai+(ai-1)` for some `k`.

This means, if any solution exists, the range of X values will be between `k*min(ai)` and `(k+1)*min(ai)` for some `0 < k <= m`.

So it might be worth to first get the range of possible results and then check the individual values only within the range.

Resulting algorithm:

```
// compute X/ai sum
long long summarize(long long ar[], long long n, long long X)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += X/ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    long long *ar = new long long[n];
    long long ar_min = LLONG_MAX;
    for(long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> ar[i];
        ar_min = min(ar[i], ar_min);
    }

    // lowest possible k
    long long k = m / (ar_min * n);
    // get the value k for a possible range of X values
    for (; k <= m; k++)
    {
        auto x = ar_min * (k + 1);
        long long sum = summarize(ar, n, x);
        if (sum > m)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    long long X_min = k * ar_min, X_max = (k + 1) * ar_min;
    long long result = 0;
    // count possible X values
    for (long long x = X_min; x < X_max; x++)
    {
        long long sum = summarize(ar, n, x);
        if (sum == m)
        {
            ++result;
        }
        else if (sum > m)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << result << endl;
}
```

It got a bit more complicated than I first expected. I hope it's still some sort of improvement.

Comment: Nice algorithm. But your algorithm is slower than my latest algorithm using binary search. And yeah, your algorithm also didn't pass the time limit, it even got a lower score.

Comment: Yes, it struck me later that the title "Divide and Conqer" is the key... working on an update, but not finished yet.

Comment: Yep. Your binary searching algorithm got the same score as my binary searching version code. And, you guess it, it didn't pass the time limit.

Comment: @Aldihilmanr do you have any time critical sample testcase or are all tests blackbox for you?

Comment: blackbox unfortunately.

Comment: @Aldihilmanr How far is the score from passing? At some point it might be worth trying some micro-optimization like canceling `summarize` as soon as `sum > m`. This might (but doesn't necessarily) play nice with a sorted `ar` array. If you sort, I'd suggest you directly gather input in sorted order, don't sort after you got all inputs.

Comment: Using naive algorithm got 25 score out of 100, using binary search got 35 score out of 100. I have tried your suggestion didn't do any significant difference, and got the same score.

Comment: I changed the second half of my `get_range` function to first check whether the range is already complete, before going into recursion. But honestly, I doubt it's going to save the world - guess there's a different approach alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the expected solution for this is binary search.

Define `f(x) = sum_i f(x/a_i)`. Without loss of generality, assume that `a_i` are given in inceasing order.

Clearly,

- `f(0) = 0 < M`
- `f(M*a_1) ≥ M`
- `f(x) ≥ f(y) if x≥y`

Thus you can do binary search to find the lowest value of x such that `f(x) = M`, with `start = 0` and `end = M*a_1` as the initial limits for the binary search.

To find the upper limit for x, do another binary search or just loop through all values in the array to find the smallest `y` such that `floor(y/ai) > floor(x/ai)` for some `i`.

Comment: Share your binary search code, perhaps that could be improved.

Comment: The problem is not the binary search but the while loops you have after binary search. That takes too long. You should use binary search to find the lowest value of mid that works instead of breaking at the first instance. And use another binary search to find the first value where gives greater func.